# How to filter Excel pivot table based on Cell value?

Tags: excel, vba, uitableview, pivot, cell

I have issue on the last line.

I want to auto filter using the cell value in cell I1, which is a resume of all dates with function `Max`, so the last date available.

```vb
Sub Y01PivotTableFilter()
    'filter last date

    'variables
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim DateField As PivotField
    Dim DateValue As String

    'Filter data
    Set pt = Worksheets("OS report").PivotTables("Statut")
    Set DateField = pt.PivotFields("Date")
    DateValue = Worksheets("OS report").Range("I1").Value

    'Update pivot table date
    With pt
        DateField.ClearAllFilters
        DateField.CurrentPage = .DateValue
    End With
End Sub
```

I have discovered my coding may work, but I have date format issues. With another auto function, to filter Date Field as Equal, it reverses dd/mm as mm/dd. I work with French date format, and got replaced under VBA with US date format, even so my regional settings are French dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: `DateValue` is a variable, not a field name.  First try would be to remove the period before it on the last line.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me
is it that line which is wrong?
    DateValue = Worksheets("OS report").Range("I1").Value

Comment: No, `DateField.CurrentPage = .DateValue` s/b `DateField.CurrentPage = DateValue`

Comment: Sorry my bad, I don't how the dot appeared

Sub Y01PivotTableFilter()

'filter last date

'variables
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim DateField As PivotField
Dim DateValue As String

'Filter data
Set pt = Worksheets("OS report").PivotTables("Statut")
Set DateField = pt.PivotFields("Date")
DateValue = Worksheets("OS report").Range("I1").Value


'Update pivot table date
With pt
DateField.ClearAllFilters
PivotField.CurrentPage = DateValue
End With
End Sub

Comment: However, when I run the Macro, still appears the bug on the last line
    PivotField.CurrentPage = DateValue

Comment: You are not using the `With` statement correctly.  You have already `Set Datefield` to include `pt`.

Comment: Sub Y01PivotTableFilter()

    'filter last date

    'variables
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim DateField As PivotField
    Dim DateValue As String

    'Filter data
    Set pt = Worksheets("OS report").PivotTables("Statut")
    Set DateField = pt.PivotFields("Date")
    DateValue = Worksheets("OS report").Range("I1").Value


    'Update pivot table date

    DateField.ClearAllFilters
    PivotField.CurrentPage = DateValue

    End Sub

Thanks Darrel, I understand your logic. I have removed the With, in conflict as you have mentioned. Still got bug on the last line.

Comment: Darrel, actually I have discovered my coding may work, but I have date format issues.
With another auto function, to filter Date Field as Equal, it reverses dd/mm as mm/dd. I Work with French date format, and got replaced under VBA with US date format, even so my regional settings are French dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Y01PivotTableFilter()

'filter last date

'variables
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim DateField As PivotField
Dim DateValue As String

'Filter data
Set pt = Worksheets("OS report").PivotTables("Statut")
Set DateField = pt.PivotFields("Date")
DateValue = Worksheets("OS report").Range("I1").Value


'Update pivot table date

DateField.ClearAllFilters
PivotField.CurrentPage = DateValue

End Sub
```